# What is the unit of bitmap.getWidth() or bitmap.getHeight()

Tags: android, bitmap

The developers [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getHeight%28%29) simply states that getHeight() will return the bitmap's height, but can someone tell me that is in pixel unit or dp unit?

Comment: That is view.getHeight(), not bitmap. The downvote is ridiculous, I won't ask this if I can easily google that information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pixel. In Java code you usually work with pixels, e.g. a view's width and height.

Comment: its actually in density pixels.

Comment: @VulovicVukasin I don't think it is. I just logged the height and width of a bitmap and then compared the output to the height and width given by the details of an image from a file manager (which I presume gives it in pixels). They match, so I think it is pixels.

Comment: How is it possible a selected answer with 15 up votes is a WRONG answer? It's in dp not in pixel.

Answer (score 2):

After Hours of Experimenting I found that it actually return height in dp units.You can verify it by changing the device screen in emulator.

Answer (score 2):

`bitmap.getWidth()` returns width in `dp` unit or `densitiy`.

To get `dpi` (density per inch) for a device, use

```
float dpi = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

> To convert dp to px

```
float px = dp * dpi;
```

> and to convert px to dp

```
float dp = px/dpi;
```

Comment: DPI = Dot Per Inch; px = dp * DPI / 160

Comment: @Zanna what is the need for dividing it by 160?

Comment: 1dp corresponds to about (not exactly) 1/160 inch (0.15875mm). Or 1dp corresponds to 1px on a screen resolution of 160DPI (DENSITY_MEDIUM). Your formula is correct, but the variable name "dpi", float dpi = DisplayMetrics().density, is misleading, because that is a scale factor, according to the documentation (and it is not even a density, despite its name). The screen resolution (the linear density of pixels on the unit length of an inch) is generally expressed in DPI and it is in DisplayMetrics.densityDpi. While DisplayMetrics.density = DisplayMetrics.densityDpi / 160, is a scale factor.

Comment: This is the wrong way around

Answer (score 0):

If you read on how android deals with views this not clear at all.  See ["Supporting Multiple Screeens"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).  After reading that document I have come to the conclusion that "it depends."  (And I'm still guessing as I have not verified my analysis.)  If the View was declared with size "wrap_content", "fill_parent", or "dp" then you get "dp", otherwise you get pixels.  If you used "dp" then scaling to pixels is achieved by multiplying by

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

For 160 dpi screen, this returns 1.0; for 320 pi screen this returns 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by getResources()....density.

Comment: Please add some additional information to better relate your answer to the question.

Comment: getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density